# 解法を促す書き込みはコメント欄ではなく回答欄に書いてほしい

Tags: 討議, コメント

以下のような、質問へのコメントのやりとりだけで解決するケースをときどき見かけます。

> 質問「◯◯◯を試したがエラーが出ます」
>
> > コメントA「設定△△△が間違っているのではないでしょうか？」
> >     コメントB「エラーメッセージに書いてあるとおり×××が足りないのが原因です」
> >     コメントC「×××を修正したら直りました。ありがとうございます」
>
> 回答 0件

この場合はコメントBがきっかけで問題が解決したことになりますが、書き込みが回答欄ではないため承認することができません。質問者から見れば回答してくれるならばコメント欄であろうが回答欄であろうがどちらでも構わないかもしれませんが、そのような例が多くなればなるほどQ&Aサイトとして成立しなくなる気がします。

質問へのコメントは、「質問内容の曖昧さを指摘」することや「詳細な情報の追加を促す」ために利用して、上記の例のような「解法を促す書き込み」はコメントではなく回答として書き込まれる方が適切だと思うのですがどうでしょうか？

Comment: 関連するメタ投稿に [コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1812/) があります。第三者でも出来る行動としてご参考までに。

Answer (score 20):

その通りかと思います。
恐らくですが、
質問者の質問内容に不足点があるなどで回答に自信が持てない方がコメントに書くのかと思います。
あくまでコメント欄は不足点などを要求する場なので、
憶測回答でも一度回答として出しておき、後日質問内容に修正があった場合、
追記修正を行えばいいと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか？
コメント欄に回答（？）を記述するシチュエーションが他にあれば
また、別の解決方法が模索できるかと思いますが……。

Answer (score 10):

そのようなルールづけには反対です。

まずコメントと回答ではシステム上「信用度」の扱いが異なります。つまりコメントは回答に求められる責任や、結果として得られるリターンを放棄しているのです。それだけが理由ではないでしょうが、あえてコメント欄に回答を書くユーザーは多かれ少なかれ回答よりも軽い気持ちで投稿していると思います。

しっかりとした回答を書かない理由は指摘のある通り自信がないからかもしれませんし、問題に深くコミットする気がないだけかもしれません。いずれにせよコメントで回答をするなと決めたところで減ったコメントがそのまま回答に代わるとは思われません。

とはいえ未承認の質問が放置されるのも好ましくないので、コメントしたユーザーの意向に関係なく第三者が清書した回答を投稿するような流れにするのが良いと思います。元の投稿者は気分を害するかもしれませんが、次はコメントではなく回答をしようと考えるでしょう。

Answer (score 6):

「回答」するにはまだまだ情報が足りなく、助言にしかならない場合には、コメントにしております。
もしそのやりとりの中で回答に辿り着いたなら、あらためて回答を投稿するのが分かりやすいですし、質問も閉じやすいのではないかと思います。

コメントも限定されたフォーマットなので、例えば複雑な設定のxmlなどを例示するには適しませんし、それを回答に書けるかどうかは、質問内容次第ではあります。