# コメント欄で回答が出てそのまま未解決のまま放置されているものについて

Tags: 討議

よく、未解決のところにコメント欄でそのまま解決してしまい、回答には何も書かれていないという状態をよく見かけるのですが、これについてどうすればいいと思いますか？

Comment: 重複候補: [コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1812/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba%e6%b8%88%e3%81%bf%e3%81%a8%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e4%ba%8b%e5%be%8c%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86)

Comment: 関連: [解法を促す書き込みはコメント欄ではなく回答欄に書いてほしい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1938/19110)

Answer (score 2):

質問がはっきりしており、コメントに書かれた内容が質問に対する明確な回答になっていると判断できるのであれば、その内容を回答として投稿してください。もし、単なる転載によって自分が信用度を獲得することをよしとしないのであれば、「コミュニティwiki」にチェックを入れてください。

正しい内容でもコメントが回答としての品質を満たさない場合は、そうなるように考えて回答を投稿してください。例えばリンクだけのコメントであれば、リンク先の内容を自分の言葉で要約し回答として成立するようにしてください。

コメントの中には闇雲につけられた思いつきレベルのものも多くあります。内容が正しいかどうか、質問の意図を正しく反映しているかどうか、が判断できなければ、回答として転記するのは避けてください。