# コメントで解決した質問には、回答を投稿してほしい

Tags: サポート, コメント

モデレーションツールで「最近削除された質問リスト」を眺めていたところ、コメント欄で問題が解決し、そのまま放置されていた質問が自動削除されていることに気づきました。

というのも、[この投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/341401)によると、メインサイトに投稿された質問は、

- 質問されてからの経過日数が365日より長く、かつ、
- [lock](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) されておらず、
- 回答が投稿されておらず、
- スコアが 0 以下で、
- (閲覧数) ≦ 1.5 × (質問されてからの経過日数) で、
- コメント数が 0 〜 1 である

……ようなとき、システムによって自動削除 (`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`) されるのです。この自動削除が起こるには少なくとも 1 年かかるので目立っておらず、私は今まで気付いていませんでした。

しかし、折角解決した質問が削除されてしまうのはもったいないです。そこで、もしコメントで問題が解決した場合は、 **その内容を回答として再投稿して下さいませんでしょうか？**

私自身、回答に確信が持てないとき、解決案をコメントに書きたくなるときがあります。その他の理由で回答をコメントにしたいときもあるでしょう。それでも、解決した場合は回答としてご投稿願えませんでしょうか。また、第三者の方も、コメントで解決している質問を見つけたら、[コミュニティ wiki として投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1812/19110)して頂けませんか？

回答が投稿されていれば、少なくとも上記の理由で自動削除されることはありません。いかがでしょうか。

#### 参考

- [コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1812/19110)
- [解法を促す書き込みはコメント欄ではなく回答欄に書いてほしい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1938/19110)